# "Bool" not found in .NET application running on Mono/XPS

Tags: asp.net, mono

I am incredibly new to .NET and Mono. I have a .NET 4 application that I am trying to run locally, and I'm getting a compilation error when I try to run it (using xps4 on Ubuntu). At the end of the stacktrace it says:

/tmp/jeremy-temp-aspnet-0/3b8f3547/App_Web_635c7158_48.cs(32,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `bool' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Does that mean that it doesn't recognize the boolean type? A Google search wasn't much help.

**Update** - Here's the code:

```
public virtual @bool ShowRecentPlans {
     get {
        return ((@bool)(this.GetPropertyValue("ShowRecentPlans")));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you prefix an identifier (like a type name) with `@`, you're telling the compiler that, even though it looks like a reserved word, it refers to something defined in your program.

Unless you have something defined somewhere like

```
public class @bool
{
...
}
```

then this isn't going to work.

Try

```
public virtual bool ShowRecentPlans { 
     get { 
        return (bool)(this.GetPropertyValue("ShowRecentPlans")); 
     }
}
```

For instance, if you wanted to use the keyword `new` as an identifier, you could:

```
int new = 5; /// error!
int @new = 5; /// compiles
```

`@` is of course also used to tell the compiler how a string should be interpreted.

```
// throws an error because \p and \m look like formatting sequences
var path = "c:\pub\myFile.txt"; 
// compiles 
var path = @"c:\pub\myFile.txt";
```

Also, I just have to ask: what made you use `@bool` instead of `bool` to start with?

(And, for the record, using a keyword as an identifier is a very, very bad idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Your return type should be `bool` instead of `@bool`.